# Confused about Amazon DynamoDB, what is per hour for units of write capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been working on a new project and have put some data on `Amazon DynamoDB`. The project was kind of on hold last month and I was surprised to see such high costs for a DB that was essentially almost untouched for the whole month.

Here is the bill details:

[image]

What does `per hour for units of write capacity beyond the free tier` mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pay for the provisioned capacity, if for example you request 400 WCU's then Amazon needs to reserve capacity to make sure you will be able to use all those WCU's. So even if you don't write anything you still need to pay Amazon for the reserve they have to make. This is the capacity you have to pay for which you have used beyond what you got for free in the free tier. This is also the reason why you should choose your provisioned capacity carefully, even if you use auto scaling. Constantly monitor your usage is key to using AWS.

I think for the table you have quite some capacity provisioned and that's where I would start looking. If you are sure a table will not be used for a prolonged time I would dial down the provisioned capacity, even with auto scaling enabled. That being said it might be a good idea to check out auto scaling and see if it could have helped you here.